# Does Craft Commerce support Worldpay refunds?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

If anyone else is using Worldpay with Craft Commerce (am starting to feel like I'm one of a very small number), do you have order refund functionality? As in, the Refund button that exists on the order page with the control panel.

Comment: Not a solid answer, but Commerce is looking to see if an Omnipay gateway supports a "refund" method.  Their JSON Gateway [does](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-worldpay/blob/master/src/JsonGateway.php#L68), but their "normal" gateway [does not](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-worldpay/blob/master/src/Gateway.php).

Comment: Ah, right. Unfortunately everyone I work with seems to be using their 'normal' gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer looks to be "Not if you're using the Legacy gateway" that all my clients seem to be using.